# Звук при событии

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

**upd**: разобрался. Шаманизм ситуации в том, что разные браузеры поддерживают разные форматы звука =\

Проблема, как мне видится, не слишком сложная, но что-то не клеится.

Нужно при событии (`onmouseover`) проигрывать коротенький звуковой сэмпл (`sound.mp3`)

Пробовал реализовать добавлением `<embed>` при событии. Работает, но возникает неслабая задержка - что не круто.

Есть ли некий аналог `.play()` для `<embed>`? Или стоит колдовать с `<audio>`?

C `<audio>` шаманизм какой-то происходит. Беру пример прям из w3schools, а он не работает =

(Mozilla 11.0 / Chrome 17.0 / Opera 11.6)

Идеальным было бы решение в стиле:

```
function play(whatToPlay) {
    document.getElementById(whatToPlay).play();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SoundManager 2**](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/).

Comment: лови халяву )